# conflicting intmax_t definitions - Boost 1.53 and gcc 4.8 incompatibility?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu Trusty Tehr, and now the C++ project I'm working on won't build.

It looks like the stdlib and Boost aren't working nicely together for some reason.  A bunch of typedefs are conflicting between the two, below is one of the errors, where intmax_t is getting defined in two places.  I'm not sure what changed, but I now have gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-14ubuntu2) 4.8.2  and boost Version: 1.53.0.0ubuntu2

Here's an example error message:

```
/usr/include/inttypes.h:290:8: error: reference to ‘intmax_t’ is ambiguous
extern intmax_t imaxabs (intmax_t __n) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
    ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h:9:0,
             from /usr/include/inttypes.h:27,
             from src/uint256.h:11,
             from src/key.h:12,
             from src/crypter.h:8,
             from src/keystore.h:8,
             from src/script.h:14,
             from src/script.cpp:11:
/usr/include/stdint.h:134:19: note: candidates are: typedef long int intmax_t
typedef long int  intmax_t;
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/math_fwd.hpp:12:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/math/common_factor_ct.hpp:13,
             from /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:44,
             from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
             from src/script.h:12,
             from src/script.cpp:11:
/usr/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:306:50: note:                 typedef boost::long_long_type boost::intmax_t
  typedef  ::boost::long_long_type            intmax_t;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm fine with downgrading something, I'm just not sure what to downgrade.

Comment: Did you write `using namespace boost` somewhere? Make a copy of your code, then remove as much as you can while keeping the same error (probably just 2 or 3 #includes) and report that to your distribution.

Comment: I do have using namespace boost in a few places, but it worked fine before.  That's the thing, it worked fine and then it didn't.  I'm surprised I'm the only one seeing this (though maybe most people haven't upgraded to whatever new version I have?).  I'll try to narrow it down, but it seems like something basic in one or the other things changed and needs to be fixed.  Am I wrong?  Why did it work before if it now breaks?  It seems like what changed is, boost now defines its own intmax_t (and other such things) and this is just plain wrong.

Comment: Even if `using namespace boost` works, it is still fragile. For the cstdint.hpp issue, the macros are not making boost use the right part of this file, but we are missing too much to say why. If you preprocess just `#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>` and grep for intmax_t in the result, do you still see ::boost::long_long_type? As I said, first reduce your example to something just a few line long that you can post here (without forgetting to copy the command line you are using to compile).

Comment: I actually managed to fix it by just moving a using namespace boost line below some includes and then manually specifying boost:: on a few declarations.   I appreciate the suggestion to look for a using namespace boost line.  This is a side project, and I honestly don't have a lot of time to debug why boost and the standard library started conflicting where before they had not been.